# StackOverflow error when building Maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, build, stack-overflow

I'm working on a 3 project solution which is broken down as below :

Common : holds all common classes such as Service and Dao classes, Entities and all the common libraries both projects use such as Spring, Hibernate, Log4J2, etc.

Web client : web app the users see and interact with.  Has a dependency for the common project in its POM.XML.

Service : handles message communications, multiple socket connections, DB maintenance, automates certain tasks, etc.  Also depends on common lib.

Before today, only the service project had spring boot as its parent because i had not explored using spring boot in a web app before.  Now that I have, BOTH projects now use spring boot as the parent so i have now moved the parent section to the common project.  Since doing this move and removing the parent declaration from both child projects, only the service project builds and runs correctly.

I know the web client's code is fine because it worked perfectly before i did the POM changes (tested after switching to a spring boot style as well).  When trying to clean and build the web client, i get this strange stack overflow error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
at org.apache.maven.cli.PrintStreamLogger.info(PrintStreamLogger.java:110)
at org.codehaus.plexus.logging.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:51)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:464)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext(AbstractArchiver.java:467)
```

As you can see, the last line just repeats indefinitely.  The web client runs an embedded Tomcat server and is packaged as a jar file.  Here are both POM.XML files (I'm not including the service project's POM file because it works fine) :

Common :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!--SPRING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!--MICROSOFT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--HIBERNATE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--HAPI-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v26</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v25</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v24</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v231</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v23</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v22</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-structures-v21</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>MDHIS_Common</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Web client :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
<artifactId>MDHIS_WebClient</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>MDHIS_WebClient</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!--JAVA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--TOMCAT-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JASPER-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SIGAR-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MDHIS_COMMON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
        <artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>MDHIS_WebClient</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have a feeling this is due to my plugin section in the web client's POM.XML file but i'm using pretty much the same in a test project i did prior to switching to spring boot and it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are working against the framework. Don't use the assembly plugin use the spring boot plugin.

Comment: you mean like this?

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Comment: Yes. Using the assembly plugin will generate a non Spring Boot jar and Spring Boot will not run with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself the hassle, just use this :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Where do you use this snippet? (a similar tag already exists in the Web Client pom) Do you need to delete other portions of the pom?

Comment: In my case i replaced all 3 maven-related plugins by the spring boot maven plugin and that was the end of it.  I was effectively working against the framework

Answer (score 5):

So much for typing this giant post, i added this line to the maven-assembly-plugin and it fixed it :

```
<version>3.1.0</version>
```

Comment: Wrong way. If you are using spring-boot use spring-boot-maven-plugin ....

Comment: indeed, I switched to the spring boot plugin, MUCH simpler.  There is a lot to learn about all this stuff but i'm getting there!

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to try here is to change the JDK version. I've had this issue for quiet a while and changing the JDK version eventually fixed it. I was on JDK 1.8.0_202 and I switched to 1.8.0_117